# geom_smooth plot labels cut out both at the left and right hand side in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making line graphs using ggplot and geom_smooth but my plotted line labels are getting beyond the plot area. Somehow I don't know how to reduce the size of the plot or shrinking the lines.
My code is like this.

```
    ggplot(br1, aes(x = Year, y = BirthRate, colour = Country, group = Country)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Country), method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 0.7)) +
  labs(title = "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~region, 2)
```

The data is being produced below:

```
br1 <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", 
"India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "World", 
"South Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle income", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
"Euro area", "Middle East & North Africa", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"North America", "Low income"), region = c("South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"), 
    Year = c("1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", 
    "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", 
    "1998", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", 
    "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", 
    "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", 
    "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", 
    "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", 
    "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", 
    "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", 
    "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", 
    "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", 
    "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", 
    "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", 
    "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2004", "2004", 
    "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", 
    "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", 
    "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", 
    "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2005", 
    "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", 
    "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", 
    "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", 
    "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", 
    "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", 
    "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", 
    "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", 
    "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
    "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
    "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
    "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
    "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
    "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
    "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", 
    "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
    "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
    "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
    "2017", "2017"), BirthRate = c(48.69, 28.82, 29.3, 27.32, 
    24.27, 33.65, 36.17, 18.51, 22.34, 28.65, 42, 23.03, 9.83, 
    10.47, 25.63, 23.18, 14.01, 42.74, 48.42, 28.16, 28.17, 26.86, 
    22.68, 32.64, 35.42, 18.46, 21.91, 28.15, 41.8, 22.48, 9.71, 
    10.47, 25.08, 22.71, 13.91, 42.42, 48.02, 27.49, 27.07, 26.4, 
    21.39, 31.55, 34.7, 18.46, 21.65, 27.65, 41.6, 22.1, 9.77, 
    10.63, 24.64, 22.25, 14.04, 42.07, 47.51, 26.82, 26.01, 25.94, 
    20.44, 30.4, 34.02, 18.49, 21.31, 27.16, 41.38, 21.72, 9.44, 
    10.39, 24.3, 21.77, 13.77, 41.71, 46.9, 26.13, 25.02, 25.49, 
    19.82, 29.24, 33.38, 18.54, 21.05, 26.67, 41.16, 21.41, 9.28, 
    10.33, 24.06, 21.3, 13.66, 41.34, 46.23, 25.44, 24.11, 25.03, 
    19.49, 28.11, 32.78, 18.57, 20.84, 26.19, 40.94, 21.11, 9.28, 
    10.35, 23.91, 20.83, 13.76, 40.97, 45.51, 24.74, 23.28, 24.57, 
    19.4, 27.04, 32.24, 18.59, 20.69, 25.7, 40.71, 20.92, 9.5, 
    10.42, 23.81, 20.39, 13.66, 40.59, 44.72, 24.05, 22.53, 24.09, 
    19.47, 26.06, 31.75, 18.58, 20.55, 25.2, 40.46, 20.76, 9.76, 
    10.3, 23.77, 19.96, 13.67, 40.2, 43.87, 23.38, 21.83, 23.56, 
    19.63, 25.2, 31.33, 18.51, 20.4, 24.68, 40.19, 20.51, 9.96, 
    10.38, 23.8, 19.55, 13.97, 39.8, 42.94, 22.75, 21.17, 23, 
    19.79, 24.43, 30.96, 18.4, 20.31, 24.14, 39.9, 20.36, 10.21, 
    10.38, 23.89, 19.18, 13.99, 39.38, 41.95, 22.15, 20.55, 22.39, 
    19.86, 23.77, 30.63, 18.25, 20.2, 23.57, 39.58, 20.22, 10.75, 
    10.55, 24.01, 18.85, 13.73, 38.95, 40.9, 21.61, 19.95, 21.75, 
    19.81, 23.19, 30.34, 18.06, 20, 22.99, 39.23, 20.03, 10.78, 
    10.34, 24.14, 18.55, 13.28, 38.51, 39.83, 21.11, 19.4, 21.11, 
    19.59, 22.69, 30.08, 17.84, 19.78, 22.41, 38.86, 19.77, 10.54, 
    10.36, 24.26, 18.27, 12.81, 38.07, 38.75, 20.66, 18.91, 20.5, 
    19.17, 22.26, 29.86, 17.59, 19.6, 21.87, 38.45, 19.58, 9.97, 
    10.16, 24.33, 18.02, 12.53, 37.63, 37.69, 20.25, 18.51, 19.92, 
    18.6, 21.88, 29.67, 17.34, 19.49, 21.36, 38.01, 19.45, 9.98, 
    10, 24.35, 17.78, 12.44, 37.19, 36.67, 19.86, 18.2, 19.42, 
    17.94, 21.52, 29.49, 17.09, 19.28, 20.92, 37.56, 19.26, 9.64, 
    9.74, 24.28, 17.55, 12.24, 36.76, 35.71, 19.5, 17.96, 18.98, 
    17.2, 21.18, 29.32, 16.85, 19.2, 20.53, 37.08, 19.15, 9.93, 
    9.79, 24.12, 17.32, 12.33, 36.32, 34.81, 19.16, 17.78, 18.62, 
    16.42, 20.84, 29.12, 16.61, 18.98, 20.2, 36.61, 18.89, 9.89, 
    9.66, 23.85, 17.09, 12.23, 35.89, 33.98, 18.82, 17.62, 18.33, 
    15.64, 20.52, 28.89, 16.36, 18.96, 19.91, 36.13, 18.91, 10.13, 
    9.71, 23.49, 16.85, 12.04, 35.47, 33.21, 18.5, 17.46, 18.08, 
    14.89, 20.2, 28.6, 16.11, 18.63, 19.65, 35.67, 18.54, 10.28, 
    9.48, 23.06, 16.61, 11.65, 35.04)), row.names = c(NA, -360L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, The labels are cut off by the plot area [image: the picture below]. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xlim` to extend x-axis on both the ends by 1 year.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

br1 <- type.convert(br1)

ggplot(br1, aes(x = Year, y = BirthRate, colour = Country, group = Country)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Country), 
          method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 0.7)) +
  labs(title = "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~region, 2) + 
  xlim(c(min(br1$Year) - 1,max(br1$Year) + 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it got better. I found this line also `scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.7))` is of some use.